# Método similar a GetUserId() o implementar Claim con un array de enteros

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto ASP.Net MVC con Cuentas individuales de usuarios (Identity). El proyecto también necesita ser vinculado con los usuarios de un sistema ya existente de la empresa, lo cual ya se hizo con una relación muchos es a muchos como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Referencia de la relación de usuarios entre ambas implementaciones]

La tabla intermedia podría quedar con el siguiente resultado:

```
IdUsuarioBase | IdUsuarioDemo
-----------------------------
abc-12a-34c   | 123
abc-12a-34c   | 456
efg-56i-78j   | 789
klm-90o-12p   | 789
```

`UsuarioBase` alude a Identity mientras que `UsuarioDemo` a los usuarios del sistema existente de la empresa.
La idea es generar algún método similar a `User.Identity.GetUserId()` pudiendo quedar algo así como `User.Identity.GetUserIdDemo()`, en donde pueda entregar todos los `ID` del usuario demo asociados al `ID` del usuario base que inició la sesión ó agregar una propiedad en la clase `IdentityModels` donde entregue los `ID's` a través de una lista o arreglo que luego pueda ser llamado desde un `Claim`.

```
Resultado: abc-12a-34c => [123, 456]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias crear un `extension method` para extender la funcionalidad de la clase que expone la propiedad `Identity`

[Métodos de extensión (Guía de programación de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Entonces tomando el Id del usuario que se autentica instancia el dbcontext y generas el linq para consultar los usuarios relacionados

```
public static class IdentityExtension{

    public static List<int> GetUserIdDemo(this IIdentity identity)
    { 
       //aqui realizas la query linq 
    }
}
```

con esto tendras ese metodo que extiene `IIdentity` y tendras listado el metodos

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, Leandro! ¡Funcionó de 10 y como exactamente esperaba!